# Use wget from sh script

Tags: bash, sh

I want to use wget in sh script but I don't want to download wget url.How can I do this ? This script is getting load average with this code `uptime | awk -F'[a-z]:' '{ print $2}'` and I'll pass this values to php script with wget.

Comment: This question is very unclear as currently written. What do you mean "don't want to download wget url"? Do you mean you don't want to save contents to a file, but instead pipe them? What does `uptime` have to do with wget at all?

Comment: I couldn't understand it either.

Comment: Do you mean you want to pipe the output of `wget` to a script?

Comment: Yes I don't want to download url as a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pipe the document instead of downloading it to a file, use the `-O` option:

```
wget -O - URL | command
```

Redirecting to the filename `-` means to send to standard output instead of a file.

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble understanding your question, but I will attempt to rephrase it and suggest a solution.

My guess is that you want to show the load averages of a remote server on a webpage, via php.  With that assumption, let me show you an easier way to do that.  This way requires that you have access via ssh to the remote computer, and that your local computer can access the remote computer with a ssh key.

Basically, you will use ssh to execute a command on the remote machine, then save the output (load averages) locally (somewhere that your web server can access them).  Then you will include the load average file in your php script.

First, you need to get the load average of the remote computer and save it locally. To do so, run this command:

```
ssh [remote username]@[address of remote computer] "uptime" | awk -F'[a-z]:' '{ print $2}' > [path to where you want to save the load average]
```

Here is an example:

```
ssh jake@10.0.0.147 "uptime" | awk -F'[a-z]:' '{ print $2}' > /var/www/load_average.txt
```

Next, you need to setup your php script, it will looking something like this:

```
<?php
include "load_average.txt";
>
```

You should also setup a cronjob to request the information regularly so that it is up to date.